# Regular expression to match 1-5 symbols when start symbol letter and at least one number

Tags: c#, regex

I tried this expression:

```
/([a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*){1,5}$/
```

but it's works for every word that start with letter and contains at least one number and more then two symbol for example "re1111e" when its not supposed to, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include some valid (and invalid) matches?

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to write your regex uses a positive lookahead to check for a number:

```
/(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,4}/
```

This pattern says to:

```
(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])     assert that a single digit appears somewhere
[a-z]                match an initial letter character
[a-z0-9]{0,4}        then match zero to four letter or number characters
```

Comment: This matches the input `aaaaa` part of the test input `aaaaa1`, because the positive lookahead doesn't care *where* it finds the digit. I think you need the full `/(?=[^0-9]{0,4}[0-9])[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,4}/`

Comment: I think you should have this : `^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-z][a-z0-9]{0,4}$`, it depends on the input and the expected output. @Caius: Can you provide some examples? On the other hand, there is another problem : For example, in the input string `a1b2c3d4e5` I suppose you want to capture `a1b2c` and `3d4e5`, but do really you want omit `b2c3d` for example ?

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern, the quantifier `{1,5}` apllies to the group repeating this match `[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*` 1 - 5 times.

If I am not mistaken, you want to match `[a-z]` from the start followed by 4 chars from which one of them is at least 1 digit so the minimum amount of characters is 2 and the maximum is 5.

You might use:

```
^(?=.{2,5}$)[a-z][a-z0-9]*[0-9][a-z0-9]*$
```

*About the pattern*

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{2,5}$` Assert string length 2 - 5 characters
- `[a-z]` Match a-z
- `[a-z0-9]*` Repeat 0+ times matching a-z 0-9
- `[0-9]` Match a digit
- `[a-z0-9]*` Repeat 0+ times matching a-z 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtuoXU/1)